# How to comment out one line of a multiline statement

Tags: python

As shown in the following code, the `groupby` line should be commented out:

```
lines = fileinput.input(fin) \
        | take(300) \
        | where(lambda x: not x.strip().endswith(',,,,,')) \
        \ # | groupby(lambda x: x[42]) 
        | teeFile(fout,100)
```

However, the above syntax - and several variations on it - does not work:

```
 \ # | groupby(lambda x: x[42])
                                                                                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Another variation already attempted:

```
    # | groupby(lambda x: x[42]) \
```

Is there any way to comment out a portion of a longer statement requiring continuation characters?  Or are we just out of luck - along the lines of python's inability (/unwillingness) to support inline comments?

I am on `2.7`

Here is a small update to the code snippet to make it fully self-contained.

```
import sys, pipe, fileinput ; from pipe import *;
lines = fileinput.input(fin) \
        | take(300) \
        | where(lambda x: not x.strip().endswith(',,,,,,,,')) \
        # | groupby(lambda x: x[42]) \
        | tee
```

It was just including an import now.  I get different errors in `ipython` vs `intellij`:

`ipython` :

```
File "<ipython-input-2-60c5dbee382d>", line 3
    | tee
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

`intellij` :

```
 File "<ipython-input-30-1f7b64578a1f>", line 16
    lines = fileinput.input(fin)         | take(300)         | where(lambda x: not x.strip().endswith(',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'))   \ # | groupby(lambda x: x[42])
                                                                                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: just remove the backslash at the start of the line (and put it at the end of the line

Comment: Or put the comment before the backslash.

Comment: works fine here, please provide a [mcve]. ooooh downvote... good, time to delete, well, for now...

Comment: time to provide a [mcve], there must be something else. Your "variation" should work.

Comment: ok undeleting now that another answer has been posted. Let's follow this.

Comment: my answer was wrong: inside parentheses everything works. But outside it's not possible to comment a line when there's a backslash in the previous line.

Comment: What is this `|` wizardry?

Comment: @AdiC  i asume you mean `\` and not `/` .. and the result is `invalid syntax`

Comment: @mkrieger1  check out `pipe infix notation`.  it is way cool.   https://mdk.fr/blog/pipe-infix-syntax-for-python.html

Comment: @ChristianDean  No it's actually not bitwise or :  https://mdk.fr/blog/pipe-infix-syntax-for-python.html

Comment: @ChristianDean Yes the bitwise or is what I expect `|` to be in Python. That's why I'm wondering how it seems to be overloaded to function like a pipe in the shell in this case.

Comment: @javadba Ah, my mistake. Didn't realize that your were using a library.

Comment: @ChristianDean  I actually have no idea how this `pipe` is able to overload (/stomp on ?) the bitwise or. But it is serving a useful purpose and I have other things than to dig deeper ;)

Comment: @javadba Yes, the [bitwise AND](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__and__) and [OR operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__) can be overload. I guess the library overloads the bitwise OR to behave like the pipe in the shell. The overloading logic seems to appear around [this](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe/blob/master/pipe.py#L409) line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use implicit line continuation with parentheses:

```
lines = (fileinput.input(fin)
        | take(300)
        | where(lambda x: not x.strip().endswith(',,,,,'))
#       | groupby(lambda x: x[42]) 
        | teeFile(fout,100))
```

Inside unclosed parentheses `(`, brackets `[`, or braces `{`, Python will perform line continuation automatically, even across lines with comments. The rules for [line joining with backslashes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) don't allow line continuation on a line with a comment.

Comment: ah ok. Actually `scala` behaves precisely this way as well.

Comment: Hmm. So the syntax in the question isn't possible, I assume?

Comment: @ChristianDean: Not possible. The [explicit line joining rules](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) explicitly exclude comments; only implicit line joining can continue a logical line through a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I never write line continuations characters. Why not use parentheses ?

```
>>> ( 1
... | 2
... | 3
... # foo bar
... | 4
... )
7
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `\` for line continuation. Parenthesis will do the job (and `\` is ugly...)...

```python
print((12
       + 15
       + 30))  # 57

print((12
       #+ 15
       + 30))  # 42
```

Plus, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) says so

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.